# Angularjs ng-repeat not re embedding tweets

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter

I am using angularjs to display tweets. I am using `ng-repeat` with a `filter` that is tied to the value of a `checkbox`. If ticked the filter returns all the tweets (its default value), if not it returns half of the tweets.

It initially works and displays all the tweets and when I first un-tick the box (it just returns half the tweets) which works as well. Though when I re-tick the box only half of the tweets are embedded even though all of the tweets are returned from the `filter`, (I checked that using an alert before they are returned).

Any ideas why this is happening?

```
<li ng-repeat="tweet in tweets| parsePeople:this">
    <blockquote class="twitter-tweet tw-align-center" data-lang="en">
        <a ng-href="https://twitter.com/{{tweet.handle}}/status/{{tweet.theTweet}}"></a>
    </blockquote>
    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</li>
```

**edit, here is the filter I am using**

```
app.filter('parsePeople', function() {
    return function(items, scope) {
        var list = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            if (scope.check.val)
                list.push(items[i]);
            else {
                list.push(items[i]);
                i++;
            }
        }
        alert('value is: ' + scope.check.val + ' list size is: ' + list.length);
        return list;
    }
});
```

Comment: is it possible for you to share code of your filter `parsePeople`

Comment: I am trying to replicate your issue but it seems to work fine. have a look here https://plnkr.co/edit/prP4ZlpCKUQQIkqK2J6T?p=preview. let me know if I missed something

Comment: That works fine for me as well. The problem is that it appears that twitter is not reparsing the elements after they are added subsequent times, even if I call twttr.widgets.load(); from the script beneath the blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I did in order to make this work was include jquery, and then poof, it worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

since it seems that twitter API is not parsing UI when you refresh the list I would suggest to change the approach as in below code

```
<li ng-repeat="tweet in tweets" ng-hide="!check.val && $index % 2 === 1">
    <blockquote class="twitter-tweet tw-align-center" data-lang="en">
        <a ng-href="https://twitter.com/{{tweet.handle}}/status/{{tweet.theTweet}}">{{ tweet.handle }} - {{ tweet.theTweet }}</a>
    </blockquote>

    <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</li>
```

Here instead of using `filter` I am using a `ng-hide` directive to hide odd number tweets when checkbox is un-checked. This will ensure that element is not removed from UI instead just set to `display: none` so no re-rendering is required.

Comment: This is initially what I did, Though I am going to establish a websocket and pipe in more tweets later, so I need to be able to add them after the fact